What should I do when I encounter a spam message?
I've encountered a post that contains nonsense or spam. What should I do?
This question was created by a moderator after seeing spam / nonsense being downvoted and closed but not flagged.

TL'DR Please flag spam as "spam"; nonsense should be flagged as "abusive". For questions it is recommended to also vote to close the question. Downvoting isn't necessary and costs you rep.
Moderators have the ability to destroy spam accounts. This makes it much harder for spammers as making an account takes time and effort. Accounts that post spam often remain lying in wait to spam again at the opportune moment.
Please note the following, obtained from Meta about the Spam & Abusive flags:

Each red flag, during its validity, carries an implicit downvote from the Community user, which does not affect the flagger’s reputation. This also limits the visibility of posts: on main sites, questions with a score of -4 or lower aren't shown on the front page (-8 on meta sites), and answers with a score of -3 are grayed out.
Upon receiving four red flags, the post will be locked and deleted, and the author will lose 100 reputation. (Locking means that users with the moderator tools privilege (“10k users”) cannot edit or undelete it.)

As you can see there is no real need to close it as flags will help towards the deletion. However, that will only work as long as everybody is up to date on this policy, and we're not living in Lala-land. So vote to close is fine as long as you also flag.
Do your reputation a favor and do not downvote for the simple reason that it is implied anyway.

Note that flags will always be handled, especially on this site. As we don't have a lot of mods it may take some time though, which is why the flagging and possible close votes are so important.
Of course, action will be taken if flags are abused. The abuse of flags is however not an issue on the Cryptography site at the time of writing. Please do not be afraid to flag! Most flags will be marked as "helpful" if our attention is needed somehow, and that's true for spam anyway.
